# x-powered-by: Upgrade ServiceStack/3.971 to ServiceStack/5.6.0 Win32NT/.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, servicestack

I have upgrade servicestack from 3.971 to 5.6.0 from Visual Studion NuGet. The problem I still see the last version on browser (Please see below). How can I make the update for the version to be displayed as 5.6.0? Anyone can help please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That HTTP Header suggests your project is still running ServiceStack v3.9.71 not v5.6, as  it's not possible for ServiceStack v5.6 to generate that HTTP Header.

Things you can look out for:

- Make sure the App you're viewing is the Web App you think you've upgraded
- Upgrade all projects individually to ServiceStack v5.6
- Delete the `/projects` folder, the restart the solution and make sure that you're only running the latest ServiceStack packages with the same version. If the `/packages` folder still contains v3.9.71 packages it means you still have projects referencing ServiceStack v3.9.71 packages
- Delete the Host projects `/bin` and `/obj` folders and rebuild. If this is a deployed project, delete the remote projects binaries and redeploy

Comment: I've also had 3.7x projects get "sticky" in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` folders.  That's another place to possibly clean out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks for both ansawrs.. I have tried all upove scenarios but still have the issue :-(

Here is the XML code for the web api:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="4.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="IdentityModel" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Authentication.IdentityServer" version="5.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Client" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Interfaces" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Redis" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension" version="5.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="WebActivator" version="1.5" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: This is kind of irrelevant, you need to find out why your Web App is still running the old version, if it’s still emitting a 3.971 HTTP Header than it still is.